# npm install lead to gyp ERR! build error (node-java)

Tags: node.js, node-java

i have project with nodejs & java code , the project working fine on MAC but

when trying to install project on `Windows7` 64 bit i get the following error  :

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\HDaghash\Documents\QosAdministration\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.6.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HDaghash\Documents\QosAdministration\npm-debug.log
```

i tried to install visual studio 2012 instead of 2013  as i read in some tickets on `github`  but the same issue still exist.

any one can help with this issue ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It has a dependency on node-gyp node module and node-gyp does not install in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution ...

**Java Setup**

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

**Run**

in administrator privileged command prompt window

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm update
npm install java
```